# Regex string doesn't match

Tags: python, regex

I'm having trouble matching a digit in a string with Python. While it should be clearly matched, It doesn't even match `[0-9]` `[\d]` or just `0` alone. Where is my oversight?

```
import re

file_without_extension = "/test/folder/something/file_0"

if re.match("[\d]+$", file_without_extension):
   print "file matched!"
```

Comment: Which part are you trying to match exactly? Are you trying to get the bits between the slashes? or just the filename at the end? Or literally just the number at the end?

Comment: Are you trying to check if a number is there, i.e use search, or extract the number from it, i.e re.findall?

Comment: Incidentally: always use raw strings for regexps (`r"[\d]+$"`). Otherwise you'll be back here with another mysterious problem in a few days.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read the documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match

> If zero or more characters at the **beginning** of *string*

You want to use `re.search` (or `re.findall`)

Comment: Thanks, I was only making sure the regex was right neglecting if I was even using the right function.

Answer (score 6):

`re.match` is "anchored" to the beginning of the string. Use `re.search`.

Answer (score 0):

Use re.search instead of re.match.