# Regex result negative only with Python re.match

Tags: python, regex, python-3.6

The pattern `[aeiou][^vr]e(?=[^r])` works fine when testing at RegexPlanet.com, but when I use the same pattern with `re.match` in Python I get no matches.

```
import re
pattern = r'[aeiou][^vr]e(?=[^r])'
list = ['pale.', 'taste', 'kite']
for word in list:
    if re.match(pattern, word):
        print(word)
```

Expected Result:

```
pale.
kite.
```

Comment: `re.match`, [as documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match), requires the match to be **at the start of the string**. If you just want to know if there's a match *in* the string, use `re.search` instead.

Comment: Genius! Thank you. I was starting to go bald over something so simple.

Comment: Note you could have *read those docs*, or Googled your exact problem to find e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/16569067/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/17680631/3001761, ...

Comment: My google-foo is not up to par. I greatly appreciate the help.